# Install magento twice on the same server

Tags: apache, magento, installation

I am making some test in one magento installation, but now i want to start again because all of the garbage i added to the first installation, but I need to keep it installed to see things on the admin panel and on the code...

How can I make this second installation? I tried once but the server, apache, redirects me to the second installation and I wasn't able to see the first again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many installations as you want doing :

1) Creating the folders

```
/www/docs/magento01
/www/docs/magento02
```

2) Creating the virtual hosts (as vjtemplates said):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/magento01
    ServerName local.magento01
        <Directory "/www/docs/magento01">
                SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/magento02
    ServerName local.magento02
        <Directory "/www/docs/magento02">
                SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Change your HOSTS (if you working in your local machine)

```
ubuntu: /etc/hosts
windows: C:Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt
```

And add the lines

```
127.0.0.1 local.magento01
127.0.0.1 local.magento02
```

4) Restart your server and type in your browser either local.magento01 or local.magento02 and you should be able to see your websites.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On your Apache httpd-vhost.conf, you can add as many Document Root as you want.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog @rel_logfiledir@/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog @rel_logfiledir@/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what should I do? Normal installation and then do this? On which folder should i install the second one in /docs?